# Ajax POST to Node.js through Nginx not getting correct response

Tags: node.js, ajax, nginx

I'm trying to send an ajax post request to a node.js microservice through nginx. The requuest is as follows:

```
$.post('http://localhost:80/api/signup', formData, function( data, status) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(status));
        }).done(function(data, status) {
            alert( "second success" );
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(status));
        })
        .fail(function(data, status) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(status));
        })
        .always(function(data, status) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(status));
            console.log('fiished');
        });
```

The request reaches the microservice. But the response is as follows (which is always the error function):

"data" is always:

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

And the "status" is always:

```
error
```

which is not the expected response at success nor failure.
How can I fix this?

Moreover, "formData" parameters appear as queries on the url once submitted. How can I stop that?

**Update***

I have also tried adding `event.preventDefault();` but now it gives me the following:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/signup. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

I have also tried:

```
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "http://localhost:3000/api/signup",  
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),  
        success: function(dataString) {  
            console.log(JSON.stringify(dataString));
        }, error: function(error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
```

But got the same `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` as above.

***Update***
There is a valid and possibly more detailed answer on ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource). However, I find the answer I accepted here more direct and clear.

Comment: Sounds like you're not preventing your form from submitting normally (ie `event.preventDefault()`)

Comment: Now it gives me `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present` error

Comment: @Phil Please read the question update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you executing the ajax request from the browser or localhost? If you are executing it from your browser it may be [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue. If you want to be able to execute that ajax request from your browser you should modify your server configuration/code to allow cross-origin HTTP requests.

This looks similar to your issue. [CORS issue in Jquery Ajax Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659694/cors-issue-in-jquery-ajax-post)

Comment: I updated my backend and also added a contentType to the request and removed the JSON.stringify() of formData. Now it works. Thank you @88jayto